# DB Design suggestions

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I am looking for most optimal DB Solution for the below case.

Consider that I have a Parent Table [P1] which has columns [ ID | StudentID | StudentName ], and multiple child tables derived from P1, lets say C1, C2, C3 ... [ This grows ] where every Table's composite primary key is [StudentID , ReportingDate] and other factual data respective to the table.

I have a use case where if given StudentID, I need a list of records from all the tables of the given key in the format [ Table Name | StudentID | ReportingDate ].

**Sample Input:**

Search for STD1

**Sample Output:**

```
Table Name| Searched Key | ReportingDate
C1 | STD1 | Date1
C3 | STD1 | Date1
C1 | STD1 | Date2
```

Child tables are different Reports generated based out of StudentID's on different dates and that will be growing.

I can't make joins of growing Child tables. Lets say I have 30 - 40 Child tables.

Do we have some solution for this?

Comment: No we don't have a solution for this.  You need to put some effort into it yourself before anyone is going to help.  Show what you've tried.  Paste your code into the question, and explain what doesn't work.

Comment: Okay .. I should have provided you with more context. It is not that i haven't tried. I am not a expert in DB Design .

Comment: The immediate thought that came to me is to maintain  as separate Table to track the new Child Tables . However i will end up in iteration of all the table and making  more joins , which is a costly operation i believe, Which i mentioned as "i cant make Joins " . Moreover, i am in design phase, Hence i don't have any code samples. Additionally, this is not an debugging question. I am looking for expert suggestion to tackle the situation which i may not be aware of and i am eager to know new Designs. If this is not possible i may need to  revisit the complete back end design. Thanks !

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: Please clarify via post edits, not comments. PS What is this notion that joins are problematic? Make straightforward designs using basic principles. (Joins being problematic is not one of them.) You could start learning about query optimization by reading an academic textbook. PS If you are in the design phase then give some correct design. Use DDL--even if you also give a diagram. But since you are also talking about a particular query on a particular design you can & should give a [mcve]. But a design must meet a *problem specification*--what is yours?

Answer (score 0):

More data must not lead to more tables, but to more rows in a database.

That said, you should probably have one student and one student_report table. Then add some column(s) to the student_report_table, so as to be able to reflect the different reports. In its simplest form that would be a sole report type:

- student (student_id, name, ...)
- report_type (report_type_id, description)
- student_report (student_id, report_date, report_type_id, ...)

Comment: Thanks for the input . I have tried this solution. The problem i faced here is that every report type will have its own columns. In my example, C1 will have [StudentID , ReportingDate]  but, we can have 3 factual Data. Similarly, C2 may have 5 Factual data. This was the primary reason for me to go with report wise tables.

Comment: I have no idea what this "factual data" may look like. In order to help you, we need more details. Please show some sample reports. What is it actually you want to store? The parameters used for the report? Report lines? A report layout? Pictures? PDF? XML?